# My minecraft has a very low FPS rate and freezes every second on 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, java, amd-graphics, minecraft

I recently installed Minecraft 1.7.2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with all the correct Java packages and LWJGL, but when I go to play it, the FPS rate drops to ~3 fps and freezes every second, making play almost impossible.

Specs:

- RAM: 3.6 GiB
- CPU: AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 245 Processor × 2, 2900 MHz
- GPU: GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a/integrated/SSE2
- Disk: 242.2 GB
- Java: 1.6.0_31
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I get along just fine with 1gb memory, 1.6 GHz Intel atom, and on board graphics. so it is probably a software issue. Maybe you should try reinstalling Ubuntu and possibly switching to 14.04.

Comment: Which video driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Look on the minecraft [System Requirements page](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements)

It says:

```
Recommended Requirements:
CPU: Intel Core i3 or AMD Athlon II (K10) 2.8 GHz
RAM: 4GB
GPU: GeForce 2xx Series or AMD Radeon HD 5xxx Series (Excluding Integrated Chipsets) with OpenGL 3.3
HDD: 1GB
Latest release of Java 7 from java.com
```

This may be why, you only have 3.8 GB of RAM. Also, how many GHz is your processor?

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is a resource heavy game. It could consume big chunks of RAM and CPU. A good part of it are graphics. An efficient way to reduce unnecessary computation is to reduce the "render distance" in the settings in the game itself. Also switching the "graphics" to "fast" and "smooth lighting" to "off" will help a lot. You can also switch the "clouds" off.

Also a big ammount of entities could affect the game heavily. If arround you are a lot of mobs (e.g. mob spawner) or dropped items (they despawn after some minutes). Horses, boats, carts, villagers (if there are a lot of them it could be verry buggy) are entities too. Arrows are also entities and in a lot of cases they could cause crashes too, if for example you spawn hundreds/thousands of them.

One more Problem could be custom datapacks that have big resolutions. If you use them, they consume a lot of power. So for a lower-end pc better use the standart package.